# How to add custom-control-derived TabItem to TabControl in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, controls, wpf-controls

I want to have my own base TabItem class and use other classes that derive from it.

[image]

I define base class in MyNs namespace like this:

```
public class MyCustomTab : TabItem
{
    static MyCustomTab()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyCustomTab), new  FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TabItem)));
    }
}
```

And this is what I do for the class that inherits from it:

code-behind in MyNs namespace:

```
public partial class ActualTab : MyCustomTab
{
    public ActualTab()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<MyCustomTab x:Class="MyNs.ActualTab"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Grid>

</Grid>
</MyCustomTab>
```

The error I get is "The tag 'MyCustomTab' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'". If I use `TabItem` tag in XAML the error says that it's not possible to define to different base classes.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm stupid, it should've been

```
<MyNs:MyCustomTab x:Class="MyNs.ActualTab"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:MyNs="clr-namespace:MyNs">
<Grid>

</Grid>
</MyNs:MyCustomTab>
```